# Simple thread macro implementation

Tags: clojure

Very new to clojure so might be a noob question but here it is. So I read that the `->` macro will invoke functions in sequence and I understand how this works.
`(-> (+ 1 2) (* 10))` which results in 30

But why does this not do the same?

```
(defn testing-> [a b]
  (list a b)
  first)
```

This returns a function `first` and not "a" when called as `(testing-> "a" "b")`. What am I missing here? Using it in the wrong way?

Comment: Ha! Looks like we need text highlighting for clojure here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A macro is something that restructures its input before it gets compiled.

```
user> (macroexpand '(-> (+ 1 2) (* 10)))
(* (+ 1 2) 10)
```

`testing->` is a function, not a macro, so it does not restructure the input. You would need to rearrange the input forms before evaluation to get a behavior similar to `->`. Every valid form needs to be translated into the standard clojure syntax at compile time, which is done via reader-expansion and macro-expansion.

Macro construction uses standard Clojure functions, but the semantics are somewhat unique (a macro should return the form that will be used at runtime). You can use the `clojure.repl/source` macro to see how various macros are implemented.

Any operations you need can be expressed as functions, and general creating macros should be avoided unless you need a new syntax.

Comment: It's actually a very important feature of lisps that macros are *not* a sublanguage, but are ordinary functions written in the same language, which run at compile time on source forms instead of at runtime on other values. Contrast with, for example, C, whose macros are in fact a totally distinct sublanguage, with no particular similarities to the C language proper.

Answer (score 5):

the `->` needs to be in the body of the function. it's not magic attributed to functions ending with -> but literally a macro whose name is `->` which takes a sequence of things to do and produces a new expression with the same things nested each inside the next:

```
(defn testing [a b]
  (-> [a b]
      list
      first))
```

in this exampel, when the -> macro runs it produces a new expression which looks like:

```
(defn testing [a b]
  (first (list [a b])))
```

For another example, when you call `->` with the arguemnts `(+ 1 2) (* 10)` it returns the expression `(* (+ 1 2) 30)` which is then evaluated as normal Clojure code.

PS: a macro is a function which takes a Clojure expression and produces another Clojure expression. These run In the middle of the compilation cycle and you can see what they are doing with the `macroexpand-1` function.